# Como inserir valor de timestamp em uma tabela MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, data

Eu estou recebendo um valor de timestamp de uma requisição, e gostaria de armazenar este valor em meu banco, porém quero que a coluna interprete ele corretamente.

O valor é 1416178487. 
E usando a função `date('d/m/y',1416178487);` de PHP, ele retorna a data: 16/11/2014.

Gostaria de saber se há uma configuração para que a tabela receba o valor assim: 1416178487 e mostre ele assim: 16/11/2014.

Comment: Desculpa pelo equivoco. Já esta ajustado. Obrigado.

Comment: Blz vou var um uns testes de INSERT no banco.

Comment: dê uma espiada no **[comentário do Patrick](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40674/#comment80086_40679)**, que explica como usar o `FROM_UNIXTIME` no insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode selecionar uma coluna que contenha um timestamp no MySQL como uma data nesse formato fazendo a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(coluna_timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM minha_tabela;
```

Comment: @TiagoAmaral, receio que basta acrescentar a função ao comando de inserção: `INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(1416178487))`.